# Output variable does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn PHP, but I am stuck on something. Was wondering if any of you could help me out.

The thing is, I've got a variable like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `key` LIKE 'signing_key'";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $key = $row['value'];
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);

    }
}

$Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = $key;
```

As you can see the $key variable get's it's contents from a while loop and outputs - let's just say - '12345'.

Everything looks correct, when I:

```
echo $Settings['SIGNING_KEY'];
```

it does output the '12345' on screen, as expected.

The weird thing is: when I enter:

```
$Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = '12345';
```

in my file, the module that I am trying to modify seems to work correctly. But when I enter:

```
$Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = $key;
```

for some reason the module cannot get the right signing key.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and sorry for not understanding PHP that much yet!

**Edit:**

Just a little extra explanation:

I am trying to get a string (`$key`) from the database instead of putting it hardcoded in a PHP file, so it (the `$key` variable) can be edited by everyone that has access to my website's control panel.

Comment: Because $key is being set to the very last item in the loop.

Comment: ^ String concatenation.. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Adam. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: To expand on what @Adam said `$key = $row['value'];` is overwriting its self on every iteration of the loop and you end up with the value assigned to $key in the last iteration of the loop

Comment: I'm not really sure what your end goal is and what you're trying to accomplish by looping through things and setting a variable.

Comment: Also "LIKE" in the mysql query is inefficient here, just use "="  Ex: key="signing_key"

Comment: depending on what you're trying to do, which is not totally clear you could use string concatenation as mentioned by @ficuscr `$key .= $row['value'] . ',';` or create an array out of the result `$key[] = $row['value'];`

Comment: Just a little extra explanation as requested by Adam and AnthonyPHP: I am trying to get a string ($key) from the database instead of putting it hardcoded in a PHP file, so it (the $key variable) can be edited by everyone that has access to my website's controlpanel.

Comment: *"instead of putting it hardcoded in a PHP file"* - What do you mean by that @Jannet ? Are you using more than one file and is it an included file? The question is unclear and has everyone guessing, including myself. Tip: Ping a user with the `@username` so you respond to someone in particular as I did for you here.

Comment: and as stated by @AndriyLysak earlier. Using LIKE isn't very efficient, should there be anything else looking like it. You're best using `WHERE col = '$xyz'` as an example for an exact match, given if that is what you're looking for. An added clause would also help refine the search, using/adding `AND col_x=?`.

Comment: Sorry for keeping you all wondering! :) I am editing an existing PHP script. This script used to store the key as $Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = '12345'; in a PHP file. I am now trying to get this key from the database instead, so I've put a inputfield in my webshop's controlpanel, it then stored the key to the database already (as you can see in the while loop above). But now I have to get this key to output in this file. So instead of $Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = '12345'; I have changed it to $Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] = $key; But it's not outputting the key for some reason.

Comment: I have changed the LIKE to =. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I was wondering, could it have something to do with the quotes? Does anyone know how a good way to get single quotes around the variable $key ?

Answer (score -2):

Is is possible `$key` isn't assigned probably? If you only want the first matching row change the `while` to an `if`. Also try dumping the value of `$key` and adding some error handling to your queries (as in: `mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link))`).

Comment: That is fit as a comment and you also made a mistake with the error handling. They're using mysqli_ and not mysql_. Edit: This as per original https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51755323/1

Comment: $key isn't being assigned properly, as OP has stated.

Comment: When I put <?php echo $key; ?> it outputs '12345' on screen. So I think that couldn't be it? I have also tested the database connection, but everything seems to be good there.

Comment: @JannetvanDijk Interesting, in that case '12345' should be identical to `$key`. Are you sure they're the same? What if you dump `$Settings['SIGNING_KEY']`?

Comment: <?php echo $Settings['SIGNING_KEY'] ?> outputs the same, jspcal. Also '12345' on screen